# Pinia / TypeScript Access getters from action — Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, pinia

I have a store.

```
export const useGameStore = defineStore("game", {
  state: () => gameBaseState,
  getters: {
    foundMarkers(state): Marker[] {
      return state.markers.filter((m) => m.found);
    },
    ...
  },
  actions: {
    closeAll() {...},

    nextMissed() {...},

    previousMissed() {...},

    removeFlashId(id: string) {...},

    guess(pos: Coord) {
      ...

      if (this.foundMarkers.length >= this.toFind) {
        this.setScore();
        this.status = GameStatus.Passed;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

In the `guess()` action and all over the other actions the getter values aren't found. I get...

```
Property 'foundMarkers' does not exist on type '{ closeAll(): void; nextMissed(): 
void; previousMissed(): void; removeFlashId(id: string): void; flash(text: string, 
type?: string, t?: number): void; loadLevel(levelIndex: any): void; ... 10 more ...; 
guess(pos: Coord): void; } & { ...; } & _StoreWithState<...> & _StoreWithGetters<...> 
& PiniaCustomProperties<...>'.
```

Which is basically all the **actions**. It seems like it can't infer the type of the getters (all the code runs fine, and all the getters can be accessed fine).

Have I missed something?

So far I have made sure that the `foundMarkers` getter is typed

```
foundMarkers(state): Marker[] {
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

As recommended in other forums, but beyond this I'm a bit lost in how to correctly format this.

I have also checked that the actions themselves are formatted correctly (and I think they are).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer:** Make sure **every single getter** has a return type, otherwise the parser won't be able to find any of them.

While it was obvious from answers like this:

https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1299

> You need to type the return:
>
> ```
> totalDiscount(): number | undefined {
>   return this.subTotal;
> },
> ```

The solution was to add the return type to the getter, it wasn't obvious I needed to type the return of **EVERY** getter. It must have been that the first one without a type caused all subsequent getters to fail.

I blame my lack of understanding / newness to typescript.